# How to bind domain classes to spring security user domain

Tags: grails, spring-security

I am just learning grails and have used the spring security core and spring security ui plugin. My goal is that the admin can add a user and admin will also fill up the details so users wont need to register. I have created an Employee domain for that and I can add, update, and delete already an employee. But now I want the admin to also create the user login that will be used by the employee and be changed in the future. Is there a way to bind the User domain to my current Employee domain? I tried using the customization but I think I overwritten the default codes of the controller. Can someone please help and guide me for this. Thank you!

Comment: pretty sure lots of plugins use spring security and do such behaviour I know in wschat i did something similar. maybe worth looking at existing examples such as testing demo sites of such plugins before going ahead

Comment: Can you tell me some examples that I can use? Thank you!

Comment: I think you should give an example of what you are trying to do. So far as User domain to my current Employee domain All you need to do is in the Employee domain class create a new field called User user - this will now bind the User class from spring security with the employee class. But somehow I don't think that is quite what you are after. If you can get to test the chat plugin https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-wschat-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/wschat/ChatUser.groovy  and ChatAuth.groovy   springSecurity uses ChatAuth and actual chat plugin uses ChatUser